# About Switching Displays

Tags: windows, laptop, display, switch

I have a relevant question as the previous one: I'm in a process of getting all the working parts of my dead laptop and put them in my old one. So my question is if I can switch displays. The dead one is a Lenovo V510-15IKB with a 15.6 inch-display. And the old one I'm using right now, is a Fujitsu Amilo Pi3560, also with 15.6 inch-display. I want to put the Lenovo's display on the Fujitsu for better quality if it's possible. Waiting for your answers!

(Lenovo has Intel HD Graphics 620 and Fujitsu has Nvidia Geforce GT 240M. I don't know if that matters)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances of any components being interchangeable are almost zero.

Your laptops are not only from different manufacturers but are many generations apart (something like 7 years).

Comment: Oh okk so I may have to sell the screen if I can, and not experiment to see if it can be done..Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Just strip the drive out of it for security & sell the whole thing for "spares or repairs". Let someone else figure out what bits they can use.

Comment: Yeah the last thing is to sell the parts, because they are still usable.